# Create hatch color in geom_polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a hatch color (with vertical patterns) for one of the variables (claimed) in the map below. How is this possible in ggplot2?
[image]

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data = df3,aes(x=long, y=lat))+
geom_polygon(aes(group=group,fill=policy),color="gray78",size=0.3,alpha=0.9)+
scale_fill_manual(values = c("gold","gold3","gray","forestgreen"),
                  breaks=c("Y","Claimed","N","No data"),
                  labels=c("Yes (validated)","Claimed (not validated)", "No", "No data")
    )+
labs(fill = 'WSP Policy/Regulation Formally Approved'
   ,title = 'WSP Policies by Country'
   ,x = NULL
   ,y = NULL)+
 theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 16)
    ,axis.ticks = element_blank()
    ,axis.text = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid = element_blank()
    ,legend.position = c(.14,.35)
    ,legend.background = element_blank()
    ,legend.key = element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 8),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 8)
    )
```

Comment: have a look at ggtexture https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2020/04/01/introducing-ggpattern-pattern-fills-for-ggplot/

Comment: I get an error "ggpattern is not available for R version 3.5.2" during installation

Comment: You really ought to upgrade, and I don't think ggtexture is on CRAN - follow instructions at the link to install